# Array or collection

Tags: java, arrays, collections

These points are cubic curves used by java Graphics2D libraries to draw high quality shapes such as svg the path took from Inkscape
Please Help me how to put these points in array to read them all at once instead of substitute each curve individually the code is :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dal extends Frame {

    public static void main(String[] a){
       (new Dal()).setVisible(true);
        GeneralPath g=new GeneralPath();
    }

    Dal(){
        super("Test");
        setSize(500, 500);
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
         Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
         g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

         GeneralPath path=new GeneralPath();
         path.moveTo(457.61616,470.82943 );               
            /* */
         path.curveTo(458.41016,425.70843 ,427.74316,392.55343 ,403.93516,370.91243 );
         path.curveTo(399.48516,366.83843 ,398.54916,368.02743 ,397.41516,372.27043 );
         path.curveTo(394.75116,382.25643 ,392.96616,392.69543 ,391.09516,402.03043 );
         path.curveTo(390.35916,405.62343 ,389.79116,406.92443 ,392.62616,409.52743 );
         path.curveTo(406.00316,421.83343 ,442.19716,458.07143 ,444.89016,482.76843 );
         path.curveTo(431.76716,528.31343 ,393.39116,574.56743 ,350.22516,594.56743 );
         path.curveTo(316.63916,610.12643 ,278.88716,614.34043 ,242.18316,610.35243 );
         path.curveTo(232.12112,609.27843 ,228.38012,619.29143 ,238.47016,621.92243 );
         path.curveTo(274.01216,631.28543 ,320.32416,637.73643 ,356.57416,628.91043 );
         path.curveTo(420.03416,613.46343 ,456.48216,533.71643 ,457.61616,470.82943);  

         path.closePath();
         g2d.draw(path);
         g2d.fill(path);
    }       
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Using an array won't remove the need to hardcode all these points in the code.

Comment: Does `path` allow arrays? You could store those values into a 2D array like such `Double[][] newArray = new Double[rows][3];`

Comment: Yes i want to remove the hardcode by reading each point, i thought about array to remove the complexity in my code,but i am not sure because `path.curveTo()` Adds a curved segment, defined by three new points, to the path by drawing a Bézier curve that intersects both the current coordinates and the specified coordinates (x3,y3), using the specified points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) as Bézier control points. All coordinates are specified in double precision.
Overrides: curveTo(...) in Path2D

Comment: Parameters:
x1 the X coordinate of the first Bézier control point
y1 the Y coordinate of the first Bézier control point
x2 the X coordinate of the second Bézier control point
y2 the Y coordinate of the second Bézier control point
x3 the X coordinate of the final end point
y3 the Y coordinate of the final end point
Any suggestion to simplify my code because i have other shapes the have so many points ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this suggestion, 
Create a Bezier class (inheriting from an abstract Shape), which holds all three co-ordinates. You can then build a collection of Bezier objects and create your graphics from that
 can you explain to me how to implement that via Java programmatically according to the above program ? Thanks